# Need help bounding Merten's function for large x

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, mobius-function

Recall that Merten's function is defined as:

$$M(x) = \sum_{n\le x}\mu(n)$$

Using the following prime counting functions to represent the count of integers less than $x$ with $k$ prime divisors:

$$\pi_k(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log(x)}\cdot \frac{(\log(\log(x))^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$

I obtained:

$$M(x) \sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \ \frac{x\cdot(\log(\log(x))^{k-1}}{\log(x)\cdot(k-1)!} - \left\lfloor\left(\frac{x}{\log^2(x)}\right)^\frac{1}{k}\right\rfloor$$

When I calculate the value of this equation and compare it to Merten's function it seems to be accurate, however, the value within the floor braces is off by some factor of x. This part of the equation is meant to correct for values where the mobius function is equal to 0 (when n contains a squared prime factor). I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong and any corrections would be greatly appreciated.

According to the Riemann Hypothesis, this equation should exist within $O(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ if that helps.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I worked out a new bound using ideas from Sieve Theory as follows:

$$M(x)\lt\lt -\pi(x)\cdot\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{O\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))}\right)}(-1)^n\cdot\prod_{k=1}^n{\left(\pi\left(\frac{x}{k\#}\right)-\pi(k\#)\right)}\right) \\\sim -\pi(x)\cdot\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{O\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(x))}\right)}(-1)^n\cdot\prod_{k=1}^n{\left(\frac{x\theta(k)-(k\#)^2(\log(x)-\theta(k))}{\theta(k)(k\#)(\log(x)-\theta(k))}\right)}\right)$$

Where $\theta$ is the first Chebyshev function defined by:

$$\theta(n)=\sum_{p\le x}\log(p)$$

Not sure what to do with this yet, but it is certainly more accurate than my previous bound. Hopefully I can get $\mu$ back involved in the relation. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: First of all, it's "[Mertens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Mertens)'s function", not "Merten's function". Second, the asymptotic formula for $\pi_k(x)$ is valid for fixed $k$, but it is not valid uniformly in $k$, and so the sum in the last displayed equation isn't valid (even apart from your unsuccessful attempt to remove the non-squarefree numbers). Look up the Selberg–Sathe formula for more information about $\pi_k(x)$ for $k$ varying. (By the way, one can apply the Selberg–Sathe method directly to squarefree integers, and then you wouldn't have to remove them by hand.)

Comment: I took your advice and did some research on the Selberg Sieve (I'm new to Sieve Theory). I think I found what you are talking about on pages 6-7 of this: http://math.stanford.edu/~fthorne/sieve-slides.pdf. I'm still confused at how you can be sure to account for all possible square-free products of k-primes that divide the set $A$. Is there a combinatorial method to obtaining each unique combination of k-distinct primes, whose product is less than $x$? I'm not sure I understand why the asymptotic formula given above wouldn't work for this.

Comment: While inclusion-exclusion and sieve theory are important topics in this field, they're not really suited for estimating $\pi_k(x)$. To learn the techniques needed to estimate it uniformly in $k$, you can look for example at chapters II.5 and II.6 of Tenenbaum's *Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory*.